# how to check if clicked event happend before executing focusout

Tags: jquery

i am creating an autosuggest option for my project, when the user clicks on a LI it suppose to exter the value of it to the search field but the problem is that when the user clicks it first executes the focusout event and only afterwards the click event. is there any way to switch the order of the executions? 
MY CODE:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" >
Type name:
<input type="text" id="autosuggest" class="autosuggest" autocomplete="off"/> <input type="submit" value="search" />
<div class="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <ul class="result"></ul>
</div>
<br>
some text
</form> 
<div id="results"></div>
```

and here the magic happends:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){
    var thisposition = $(this).position();
    var search_term = $(this).val();

    $.post('searcher.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data){
        $('.result').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function(){
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('.autosuggest').val(result_value);
            $('.result').html('');

        });

    });

    $('.autosuggest').focusout(function (){
        $('.result').html('');
    });

    $('div[name=dropdown]').css({
       'position' : 'absolute',
       'top': eval (thisposition.top + 27) + 'px',
       'left':eval (thisposition.left ) + 'px',
       'background':'white'
    });

});
```

});

any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the existing jQuery-UI Autocomplete widget. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @DevlshOne using an existing UI isnt as exciting as creating your oun :)

Comment: I agree, but much less aggravating. :D

Comment: @DevlshOne thats for sure :D

Comment: No, think about it: for the `click` to take place the focus has to be on the clicked-element, which means the `focusout` has to have occurred previously. You could target multiple events using `on('focusout click', function(e){/*...*/})` and then use `e.type` to test which event is occurring, but without seeing what's happening I'm not sure that's of any help to you.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: @DavidThomas i have created a JSFIDDLE but for some reason it does not work for me, on my PC it works perferctly. hope you can see something from there: http://jsfiddle.net/FLFqz/6/

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem by setting and unsetting the focusout event handler when entering and exiting the dropdown div.
here the code in case someone has the same problem:

```
            $('.dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
            $('.autosuggest').off('focusout.mynamespace');
        });
        $('.dropdown').mouseout(function() {
            $('.autosuggest').focusout(function (){
                $('.result').html('');
            });
        });
```